# Hibernate error when add @Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

i made a test with a small class using @Entity, the class had 4 vars, and all the vars was build by hibernate, but when i add another class with more than 20 vars, the hibernate just return this error:

```
    23:34:58,100 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS010418: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = Projeto01.war_org.postgresql.Driver_9_0
    23:34:58,144 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 236) JBAS011410: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'Projeto01.war#cartorio'
    23:34:58,175 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment Projeto01.war (runtime-name: Projeto01.war) in 78ms
    23:34:58,176 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "Projeto01.war" (runtime-name: "Projeto01.war")
    23:34:58,708 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for cartorio
    23:34:58,748 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 236) JBAS011409: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'Projeto01.war#cartorio'
    23:34:58,748 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 236) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: cartorio
        ...]
    23:34:58,875 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver (version 9.0)
    23:34:58,876 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS016012: Deployment deployment "Projeto01.war" contains CDI annotations but no bean archive was not found. (No beans.xml nor class with bean defining annotations)
    23:34:58,878 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS010417: Started Driver service with driver-name = Projeto01.war_org.postgresql.Driver_9_0
    23:34:58,879 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 236) JBAS011409: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'Projeto01.war#cartorio'
    23:34:58,883 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 236) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    23:34:58,885 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 236) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."Projeto01.war#cartorio": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."Projeto01.war#cartorio": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: cartorio] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:172) [wildfly-jpa-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117) [wildfly-jpa-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
        at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:463)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:182) [wildfly-jpa-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: cartorio] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1225) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.access$600(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:119) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:853) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:399) [hibernate-core-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44) [jipijapa-hibernate4-3-1.0.0.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:154) [wildfly-jpa-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
        ... 8 more
    Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: cartorio.com.br.indicar_PessoaFISICA
        at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.determineDefaultAccessType(InheritanceState.java:277) [hibernate-core-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.getElementsToProcess(InheritanceState.java:224) [hibernate-core-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:732) [hibernate-core-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3762) [hibernate-core-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3716) [hibernate-core-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1410) [hibernate-core-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844) [hibernate-core-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
        ... 13 more

    23:34:58,889 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014613: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"Projeto01.war#cartorio\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"Projeto01.war#cartorio\": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: cartorio] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
        Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: cartorio] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
        Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: cartorio.com.br.indicar_PessoaFISICA"}}
    23:34:58,892 WARN  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS011411: Unexpected problem gathering statistics: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011477: Persistence unit 'Projeto01.war#cartorio' is not available
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.management.EntityManagerFactoryLookup.entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryLookup.java:44)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.management.HibernateEntityStatistics.getDynamicChildrenNames(HibernateEntityStatistics.java:145)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.management.DynamicManagementStatisticsResource.getChildren(DynamicManagementStatisticsResource.java:204)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.registry.AbstractModelResource$DelegateResource.getChildren(AbstractModelResource.java:254) [wildfly-controller-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
...jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.ParamTag".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.ParamTag".START] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.ParamTag".START (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.ParseDateTag".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.ParseDateTag".START] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.ParseDateTag".START (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.ParseNumberTag".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.ParseNumberTag".START] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.ParseNumberTag".START (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.RequestEncodingTag".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.RequestEncodingTag".START] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.RequestEncodingTag".START (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.SetBundleTag".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.SetBundleTag".START] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.SetBundleTag".START (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.SetLocaleTag".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.SetLocaleTag".START] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.SetLocaleTag".START (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.SetTimeZoneTag".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.SetTimeZoneTag".START] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.SetTimeZoneTag".START (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.TimeZoneTag".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.TimeZoneTag".START] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.TimeZoneTag".START (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.DateParamTag".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.DateParamTag".START] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.DateParamTag".START (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.ParamTag".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.ParamTag".START] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.ParamTag".START (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.QueryTag".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.QueryTag".START] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.QueryTag".START (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.SetDataSourceTag".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.SetDataSourceTag".START] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.SetDataSourceTag".START (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.TransactionTag".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.TransactionTag".START] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.TransactionTag".START (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.UpdateTag".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.UpdateTag".START] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.UpdateTag".START (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.xml.ExprTag".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.xml.ExprTag".START] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.xml.ExprTag".START (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.xml.ParamTag".START (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.xml.ParseTag".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.xml.ParseTag".START] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.xml.ParseTag".START (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.xml.TransformTag".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.xml.TransformTag".START] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.xml.TransformTag".START (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ForEachTag".START (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ForTokensTag".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ForTokensTag".START] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ForTokensTag".START (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag".START] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag".START (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ImportTag".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ImportTag".START] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ImportTag".START (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.OutTag".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.OutTag".START] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.OutTag".START (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ParamTag".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ParamTag".START] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ParamTag".START (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.RedirectTag".CREATE (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.RedirectTag".START] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.RedirectTag".START (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 

          service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".jndiDependencyService (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.sql.ParamTag".START, service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag".START, service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.OutTag".START, service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.IfTag".START, JBAS014799: ... and 77 more ] 
          service jboss.persistenceunit."Projeto01.war#cartorio" (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.sql.ParamTag".START, service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag".START, service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.OutTag".START, service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.IfTag".START, JBAS014799: ... and 78 more ] 
          service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01 (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Projeto01.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
          service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01.UndertowDeploymentInfoService (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Projeto01] 
    JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.persistenceunit."Projeto01.war#cartorio"
          service jboss.persistenceunit."Projeto01.war#cartorio": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."Projeto01.war#cartorio": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: cartorio] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
```

full error: http://pastebin.com/wrCU0u91

Comment: do you have an field annotated with @Id in your new class?

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each `@Entity` must have an `@Id` field. You probably don't have it in your new class.

Comment: yes you was correctly, buttt i found another problem, i had 2 table class to be made by the hibernate in the persistence.xml, one was already made, and the other new, there is one way to make something like "If table no exist create" ? because if it already exist, return another big error... but the Id was one of the problems!!

Comment: @user3284660 You have to set : hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto property properly for that.