# Error creating bean 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource: Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, maven

I have been wrestling with this project now for few days and I am at a complete loss shooting in the dark. I have followed too many tutorials and still cannot get this to cooperate. I had this "working" for a bit but later came to find out that my setup did not allow for me to take advantage of repositories. So I had to take a few steps backward. Lately, I started using a hibernate.cfg.xml that has been replaced with persistance.xml but still no luck. Thanks ahead of time.

persistance.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="sample" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>com.test.sms.models.SmsMessage</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="sample" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://MasterDb0;database=SMS_SERVICE"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="username"/>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="SMS_SERVICE"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

sevlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.sms"/>
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.test.sms.models.repository"/>

<bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.GsonHttpMessageConverter"/>
<bean name="handlerMapping"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://MasterDb0;database=SMS_SERVICE"/>
    <property name="username" value="username"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.test.sms"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Configure the transaction manager bean -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Stack Trace:

```
08:05:20.398 [http-bio-8164-exec-5] INFO  o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
08:05:20.411 [http-bio-8164-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:sqlserver://MasterDb0;database=SMS_SERVICE]
08:05:20.419 [http-bio-8164-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter#3fbdd602': [entityManagerFactory]
08:05:20.420 [http-bio-8164-exec-5] WARN  o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/SMSService-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:664) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:630) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:678) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:549) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:490) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158) [servlet-api.jar:3.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284) [catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197) [catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:864) [catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134) [catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505) [catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) [catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957) [catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423) [catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.63]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.63]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_31]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1249) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.access$600(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:120) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:860) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343) ~[spring-orm-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318) ~[spring-orm-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Cannot find the expected secondary table: no smsUser available for com.test.sms.models.database.SmsMessage
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column.getJoin(Ejb3Column.java:416) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column.getTable(Ejb3Column.java:397) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindManyToOne(AnnotationBinder.java:2829) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindOneToOne(AnnotationBinder.java:3051) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1839) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:963) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:796) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3845) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3799) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1412) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
08:05:20.421 [http-bio-8164-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@792116a0: defining beans [mvcContentNegotiationManager,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,mvcUriComponentsContributor,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,sendController,messageValidator,org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigExtension#0,org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryInterfaceAwareBeanPostProcessor,foo,jpaMappingContext,smsMessageRepository,smsUserRepository,jsonMessageConverter,handlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#1,dataSource,entityManagerFactory,transactionManager,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor,org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#0]; root of factory hierarchy
08:05:20.421 [http-bio-8164-exec-5] ERROR o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/SMSService-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:664) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:630) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:678) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:549) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:490) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158) [servlet-api.jar:3.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284) [catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197) [catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:864) [catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134) [catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505) [catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) [catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957) [catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423) [catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.63]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.63]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_31]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1249) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.access$600(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:120) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:860) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343) ~[spring-orm-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.
```

SmsMessage.java

```
package com.test.sms.models;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name="smsMessage")
public class SmsMessage extends Audit {
    @Transient
    public final static String DIRECTION_INCOMING = "incoming";
    @Transient
    public final static String DIRECTION_OUTGOING = "outgoing";

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
@Column(name="timeSent", nullable=true)
private Date timeSent;
@Column(name="body", nullable=false)
private String body;
@Column(length=8, name="direction", nullable=false)
private String direction;
@Column(length=20, name="externalParticipant", nullable=false)
private String externalParticipant;
@Column(length=50, name="providerMessageId", nullable=true)
private String providerMessageId;
@Column(name="smsStatusCode", nullable=false)
@JoinColumn(table="smsStatusCode", name="code", nullable=false)
private int smsStatusCode;
@Column(length=100, name="internalUserInfo", nullable=false)
private String internalUserInfo;


@ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY, optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name="smsUserId", nullable=false,insertable = false,updatable = false)
private SmsUser smsUser;

public SmsMessage() {
    this.direction = DIRECTION_OUTGOING;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Date getTimeSent() {
    return timeSent;
}

public void setTimeSent(Date timeSent) {
    this.timeSent = timeSent;
}

public String getBody() {
    return body;
}

public void setBody(String body) {
    this.body = body;
}

public String getDirection() {
    return direction;
}

public void setDirection(String direction) {
    this.direction = direction;
}

public String getExternalParticipant() {
    return externalParticipant;
}

public void setExternalParticipant(String externalParticipant) {
    this.externalParticipant = externalParticipant;
}

public String getProviderMessageId() {
    return providerMessageId;
}

public void setProviderMessageId(String providerMessageId) {
    this.providerMessageId = providerMessageId;
}

public int getSmsStatusCode() {
    return smsStatusCode;
}

public void setSmsStatusCode(int smsStatusCode) {
    this.smsStatusCode = smsStatusCode;
}

public String getInternalUserInfo() {
    return internalUserInfo;
}

public void setInternalUserInfo(String internalUserInfo) {
    this.internalUserInfo = internalUserInfo;
}

public SmsUser getSmsUser() {
    return smsUser;
}

public void setSmsUser(SmsUser smsUser) {
    this.smsUser = smsUser;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

After a look at the stack trace I found this to be the root cause preventing your persistence unit to be properly instanced.

`org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Cannot find the expected secondary table: no smsUser available for com.test.sms.models.database.SmsMessage`

So you should check/post your SMSMessage class code.

Have you seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667715/hibernate-error-when-add-entity)?

Comment: Thank you. I should've mentioned I tried this as well, I will add it back but sadly it does not change the stack trace error.

Comment: Edit the answer "a bit". :D

Comment: I am looking over it again, and I added the class to my question. Thank you

Comment: Can you please also post the smsUser class? It seems that there is either no data/table there or hibernate can not find/instance the smsuser correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you want to use the persistance.xml and you are scanning the package name

change the following:

```
<property name="packagesToScan" value="com.test.sms"/>
```

by:

```
<property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:persistance.xml"/>
```

Comment: Adding the line caused a new issue: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/SMSService-servlet.xml];  Not sure if I am moving in the right direction or not, but at least the it's moving. Thank you.

Comment: can you put the stacktrace in a pastebin.